# Can Copper wires be used to increase linear acceleration of a ball within a circular pipe?

Tags: electromagnetism, conductors, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

Imagine you have a metal ball within a pipe and copper wire wrapped around the pipe , wherein the pipe is connected circular. Can I pass current through the copper wire such that the linear acceleration of a ball is increased?

[Here is an example of a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhxTxAfKfsc&t=1s) . Can someone also dissect this video (what the principles on which the accelerator actually works), as my question stems from this itself.

Answer (score 0):

It has pulsed coils, the video link had two. The electromagnetic coil is energized to pull the metal ball towards it, then it is shut off just as the ball reaches it and the next coil is powered to pull the ball towards it, then it shuts off just as the ball reaches it, and the cycle continues.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So the ball is metallic, not magnetic material, then what is the principle for the ball being attracted towards the coil. Also why is a pulsed coil required?

Comment: The iron ball is attracted to the electromagnetic coil. When power is  turned off at the coil it is no longer magnetic, so the balls momentum carries it past the coil. If the coil stayed on (magnetic), then the ball would stop and stay in the magnetic field. So the electromagnetic coils must be turned on and off (pulsed) at the  proper time.

Comment: Is it possible to repeat the experiment but instead of the iron ball, I have a metallic ball that is not attracted to the magnets. What conditions will be required to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Aluminum, stainless steel, brass or other material not attracted to magnets would not work,  most steel ball bearings are attracted to magnets. If a regular permanent magnet will attract it, then an electromagnet will attract it.

Comment: Ok thank you so much. Will it be possible to use a charged metal ball to experience a force?

Comment: not really in this situation, you have to turn the magnetism on and off to keep the field in front of the moving ball